# Mosquitto Dynamic Security Plugin Users and role are not add

Tags: mosquitto

i can't add any users or roles by Dynamic Security Plugin

when i enter command

```
mosquitto_ctrl -u myadmin dynsec createClient testUser
```

it doesn't give my any errors it just ask for new user password and then when i open the dynamic-security.json i can only find the admin user created

```
ubuntu@instance-20220606-2142:~$ mosquitto_ctrl -u myadmin dynsec createClient testUser
Enter new password for testUser. Press return for no password (user will be unable to login).
New password for testUser:
Reenter password for testUser:
Warning: You are running mosquitto_ctrl without encryption.
This means all of the configuration changes you are making are visible on the network, including passwords.

Password for myadmin:
ubuntu@instance-20220606-2142:~$ sudo nano  /opt/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json
ubuntu@instance-20220606-2142:~$
```

dynamic-security.json:

```
  {
            "clients": [
                {
                    "username": "myadmin",
                    "textName": "Dynsec admin user",
                    "password": "BkzzrsHWjAo0Kz444L+OVwfrI7kJZgSU5w+2AzJXh3CaI2Dgxy0ze3Vm2K8+PMaMXFwA8uAMZ9D5g1aQuMVMjg==",
                    "salt": "rhTl0xJLbYuyWq9f",
                    "iterations": 101,
                    "roles": [
                        {
                            "rolename": "admin"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "roles": [
                {
                    "rolename": "admin",
                    "acls": [
                        {
                            "acltype": "publishClientSend",
                            "topic": "$CONTROL/dynamic-security/#",
                            "allow": true
                        },
                        {
                            "acltype": "publishClientReceive",
                            "topic": "$CONTROL/dynamic-security/#",
                            "allow": true
                        },
                        {
                            "acltype": "subscribePattern",
                            "topic": "$CONTROL/dynamic-security/#",
                            "allow": true
                        },
                        {
                            "acltype": "publishClientReceive",
                            "topic": "$SYS/#",
                            "allow": true
                        },
                        {
                            "acltype": "subscribePattern",
                            "topic": "$SYS/#",
                            "allow": true
                        },
                        {
                            "acltype": "publishClientReceive",
                            "topic": "#",
                            "acltype": "publishClientReceive",
                            "topic": "#",
                            "allow": true
                        },
                        {
                            "acltype": "subscribePattern",
                            "topic": "#",
                            "allow": true
                        },
                        {
                            "acltype": "unsubscribePattern",
                            "topic": "#",
                            "allow": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "defaultACLAccess": {
                "publishClientSend": false,
                "publishClientReceive": true,
                "subscribe": false,
                "unsubscribe": true
            }
        }
```

defualt.conf :

```
listener 1882

listener 1883
#password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
protocol websockets
```

mosquitto.conf:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example
per_listener_settings false

plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mosquitto_dynamic_security.so
plugin_opt_config_file /opt/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

mosquitto version:

```
mosquitto version 2.0.15
```

could you please support my with this i can't find a solution for this i tried to google it but i couldn't find anything

Comment: Edit the question to include the `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` file, it should log the creation of new users.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem here is your `default.conf` file.

You have created a listener on port 1882 and the WebSocket listener on port 1883. It will be this second listener that is the problem.

That is because port 1883 is the default native MQTT port, by switching it to WebSockets the `mosquitto_ctrl` command will not be able to connect to send the messages required to create the new users.

I suggest you change the `default.conf` to the following:

```
listener 1882
protocol websockets

listener 1883
```

This will leave port 1883 as the default MQTT port and run WebSockets on the none standard port 1882.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case I needed to change owner of the dynamic-security.json file. When it was first created root was the owner. I changed it to mosquitto:

```
 sudo chown mosquitto:mosquitto dynamic-security.json
```

I hope it helps.